# Django Storages S3 gets all images in every query

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I Setup my project to use amazon S3 using django-storages with the S3Boto backend. Somo of my models have ImageFields that are uploaded to S3 and it's working fine.

The problem comes when I try to do a QuerySet with all() or filter(). For every request, including the django-admin ones, django is getting every image in the query set from the server.

The only change that I made is adding **width_field** and **height_field** to the ImageField to save the height and width so I dont have to retrieve the image from S3 to get this info.

It would be really helpful if anyone has any idea on why this is happening or what to do to debug this. I've been looking around at the code of S3Boto and I'm not sure what to check.

Answer (score 0):

These accesses to image files might originate from `django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField.update_dimension_fields`.

Here's what it's description says:

```
"""
Updates field's width and height fields, if defined.

This method is hooked up to model's post_init signal to update
dimensions after instantiating a model instance.  However, dimensions
won't be updated if the dimensions fields are already populated.  This
avoids unnecessary recalculation when loading an object from the
database.

Dimensions can be forced to update with force=True, which is how
ImageFileDescriptor.__set__ calls this method.
"""
```

What I would do in your case is to role our own width_field and height_field and update them only once upon image uploading. Here is how I would implement it (not tested on production with S3 yet, but work with local storage):

```
class ImageCovered(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # read and store original image data
        super(ImageCovered, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_cover_image = self.cover_image

    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,)
    # We should not use ImageField's width_field nor height_field here, since it might call S3 files.
    # Instead, we implement our own fields and update it once only upon image saving.
    cover_image_height = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    cover_image_width = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self):
        super(ImageCovered, self).save()
        # Check if cover_image has been changed
        if self.__original_cover_image != self.cover_image :
            self.cover_image_height = self.cover_image.height
            self.cover_image_width = self.cover_image.width
            self.__original_cover_image = self.cover_image #replace original data
            super(ImageCovered, self).save(update_fields=('cover_image_height', 'cover_image_width',))
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only change that I made is adding width_field and height_field to the ImageField to save the height and width so I dont have to retrieve the image from S3 to get this info.

10 years late but for any files uploaded before this change, you might need to call the related model's save() method on all objects to populate the fields.